# Calculating Hours Between 2 dates Excluding Holidays in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql

I am trying to calculate hours between 2 dates excluding holidays and weekends.
below is my holiday calendar table DDL
`create table Holiday_calender (Holiday_date date,country varchar2(20));`

below is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_hours(
    country_cd   VARCHAR2,
    start_date   DATE,
    end_date     DATE
)RETURN NUMBER AS
    v_total_hours     NUMBER;
    v_holiday_hours   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    v_total_hours :=(end_date -(trunc(start_date)+ 1))* 24;--need not to calculate hours from start date as per reuirment  
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)* 24
    INTO v_holiday_hours
    FROM
        holiday_calender
    WHERE
        holiday_date BETWEEN trunc(start_date)+ 1 AND end_date
        AND country = country_cd;

    RETURN v_total_hours - v_holiday_hours;
END;
```

above code is works fine except when end date is an holiday

`select calculate_hours('US',to_date('22-APR-2021 10:00:00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('26-APR-2021 10:33:00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM')) from dual;`

out put:-34.54 ---as expected

`select calculate_hours('US',to_date('22-APR-2021 10:00:00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM'),to_date('25-APR-2021 10:33:00 AM','DD-MON-YY HH:MI:SS AM')) from dual;`

out put:10.54 --expected  output 24

can any one suggest how to handle this situation;

> note: I don't want to add any additional sql to the function untill its necessary

Comment: There's no *magic wand* which will do it for you, so yes - I believe that you'll have to *add additional code to that function*.

Comment: As per the linked duplicate, change `COUNT` to `SUM` and total the hours for each day and use `LEAST` and `GREATEST` to limit the bounds to the `start_date` and `end_date`. Since you're working in hours (rather than fractions of days) then do the same calculation as the linked duplicate but multiply by 24.

Comment: I didn't say additional code its additional SQL statements